# SwiftUI : How to get a Navigation Title aligned with Back Button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-view

I'm trying to get the navigation title vertically aligned with the back button in a NavigationDetail view in SwiftUI. Here's what this looks like currently:

[image]

Below's my code for adding the Navigation Bar title to the view. How do I get it vertically aligned with the Back button?

```
 var body: some View {
        Text("My Detail View")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<layerSettings.count, id: \.self) { each in
    ...
   }
}
```

Comment: You want My Detail View being drawn on the same line that the Back button, having the text view overlap the navigation bar, is that it?

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to draw "My Detail View" on the same line that the Back button, try to do like this:

```
 NavigationView {
    VStack() {
       ...
    }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("My Detail View"),
                        displayMode: .inline)
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `navigationBarTitle(_:)` is Deprecated. Use `navigationTitle(_:)` together with `navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(_:)` in iOS 14.0+

```swift
NavigationView {
    VStack() {
       ...
    }
    .navigationTitle(Text("My Detail View"))
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to add `.navigationTitle(..)` and `. navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(..)` to `NavigationView` not to `VStack`.
As adding it to VStack method doesn't align title with Back button since it's a child of NavigationView. Something like below:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack() {
       ...
    }
 }
 .navigationTitle(Text("My Detail View"))
 .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```